# How can I export the feed from a group using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to export the data of my Facebook group to some sort of file for historical purposes. I understand how to use the API but I don't know what I need to do to work with it. I can make queries in the explorer but it takes way to long for it to execute. I want to know what I need to do to export the data from my group into say a text file. Even just the basic steps in order to use the API would help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use one of the Facebook SDK's in order to programmatically access the Facebook API. Some popular ones are the [JavaScript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and [PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) SDK's. The docs for each contain how to make API calls, and then you can use your code to handle the response to do whatever you want with them (as long as you stay within Facebook's policies).

An example of an API call in Facebook would be (after loading the SDK and having a valid login):

```js
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);
});
```

Let me know if that makes sense, or if you're still unclear how to approach API calls.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the feeds of the group first using graph api. Here is the code for that.

$groupFeeds = $facebook->api('/GROUP_ID/feed/?access_token='.$accessToken);
Note : $facebook is the object created of facebook class.

You have get the access token. Also you have should have the user_group permissions to extract the feeds of group.